# Package requirements doesn't make any sense

Tags: 13.04, software-center, package-management, dependencies

When trying to install the latest minitube-ubuntu from the ubuntu repository:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

minitube-ubuntu: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.7.3-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libphonon4 (>= 4:4.2.0) but 4:4.7.0really4.6.0-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libqt4-sql (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.1) but 4.7.3-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                 Depends: phonon-backend-gstreamer but it is not going to be installed
```

Seems to me that 2.17 >= 2.14, but maybe Math is different on unix-like systems? :(
What can I do to resolve these dependencies?

Following a suggestion I tried to install phonon-backend-gstreamer

```
sudo apt-get install phonon-backend-gstreamer
[sudo] password for gilnaa:
Reading package lists...
Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information...
Done
Package phonon-backend-gstreamer is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'phonon-backend-gstreamer' has no installation candidate
```

Software sources:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)]/ raring main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted
deb-src http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb-src http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe
deb-src http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb-src http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse
deb-src http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ raring partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ raring partner

# Mono and stuff.
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/geany-dev/ppa/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/geany-dev/ppa/ubuntu raring main
```

Contents of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

```
canonical-qt5-edgers-qt5-proper-raring.list                                     satyajit-happy-themes-raring.list
canonical-qt5-edgers-qt5-proper-raring.list.save                                satyajit-happy-themes-raring.list.save
dropbox.list                                                                    skype-wrapper-ppa-raring.list
dropbox.list.save                                                               skype-wrapper-ppa-raring.list.save
elementary-os-daily-raring.list                                                 steam.list
elementary-os-daily-raring.list.save                                            steam.list.save
fioan89-slidewall-raring.list                                                   tiheum-equinox-raring.list
fioan89-slidewall-raring.list.save                                              tiheum-equinox-raring.list.save
google-chrome.list                                                              tomahawk-ppa-raring.list
google-chrome.list.save                                                         tomahawk-ppa-raring.list.save
google-talkplugin.list                                                          ubuntu-sdk-team-ppa-raring.list
google-talkplugin.list.save                                                     ubuntu-sdk-team-ppa-raring.list.save
jconti-recent-notifications-raring.list                                         upubuntu-com-gtk_3_6-raring.list
jconti-recent-notifications-raring.list.save                                    upubuntu-com-gtk_3_6-raring.list.save
liferea-development-raring.list                                                 upubuntu-com-icons2-raring.list
liferea-development-raring.list.save                                            upubuntu-com-icons2-raring.list.save
opera.list                                                                      upubuntu-com-nitrux-raring.list
opera.list.save                                                                 upubuntu-com-nitrux-raring.list.save
private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_minitube-ubuntu_ubuntu.list  webupd8team-java-raring.list
private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_steam_ubuntu.list            webupd8team-java-raring.list.save
private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_steam_ubuntu.list.save
```

Comment: Do you have any PPAs enabled?

Comment: Yes, how do I copy the list and post it here?

Comment: Yes add it to your question.

Comment: Ubuntu is having an update. When the update will finish, I'll screenshot and upload it here (from some reason, not all ppa's are listed in the /etc/apt/source.list file).

Comment: You will find files for additional PPAs in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, so no need for screenshots - just show us the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and of the above mentioned directory.

Comment: @guntbert Uploaded the data you requested.

Answer (score 1):

When a dependency is not satisfied while attempting to install a package with `apt-get`, it lists the set of dependencies, including any that would be updated (it looks like you have some pending updates to install). The problem in your case is that `phonon-backend-gstreamer` is not going to be installed. You can run `sudo apt-get install phonon-backend-gstreamer` by itself, to see why it is not going to be installed.

Comment: Actually, it needn't be the gstreamer backend. Any phonon backend will do.  Search, if there are others available to you. I use the vlc backend on my 12.04 install.